# android studio not resolving third party libraries giving error 13

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Whenever I try to import a 3rd party library in my projects by including it in gradle.build file android studio is giving me error 13. Follwing is the code example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vipul.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

And following is the error:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/vipul/Desktop/experimentalandroidprojects/MyApplication6/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the  '`aapt`' file from your local drive .`Click  properties -> permissions and check 'Allow executing file as program`'.

Comment: where is it located in windows